# Use of the infinitive

Tags: infinitives

Context: "If what you scream can’t be heard over the distance, they don’t know to come and rescue you."

"don’t know to come" sounds weird to me. Is it slang or simply misuse?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @fev a manuscript I've been given, written by an American woman, presumably senior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know to do* something, you know that it needs to be done. Very common in British and American English.

> Does he know to come here (= that he should come here) first?

[Know (verb) (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/know_1)